# Accessing unique array by name

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a group of integer arrays like so-

```
public int[] box1 = {1, 0, 2};
public int[] box2 = {3, 1, 0};
public int[] box3 = {2, 3, 1};
```

What I need to do is dynamically access them by unique array name, and return a random element from it, using something like this-

```
foo="box"+2[random int];
```

where foo is my temp string including the "box" prefix, adding the number I want to "box", and getting a random element from "box2". (example: foo=3)

If I do this by string method it creates the correct nomanclature, but it's just a string, I can't use that to actually access these in script as an actual class/array element and pass them to something else.

How would I go about doing that?  Been reading the manual for hours, tried lists, but I think i'm not doing something right.  Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for `Dictionary`.

Comment: Not `Dictionary` but `Lookup`

Comment: Not ``Dictionary`` or ``Lookup`` but a custom class with an ``indexer``

Comment: Or arrays of arrays: `box[2][random int];`

Comment: I decided to leave an answer with the `Dictionary` I mentioned after no one left an answer that satisfies the syntax in your question. Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: Fantastic, I want you to know I read all of that thoroughly so I have a learned understanding of it.  Thanks for your time, answer accepted and code is working.  Fist bumps.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just break down what you actually want to do and you will see how easy it is. Just like I mentioned `Dictionary` in the comment section, you still need the two other C# features to accomplish the exact syntax.

You want to be able to do this:

```
foo="box"+2[random int];
```

which is the-same as this:

```
int valueFromArray  = arrayVariableName [index];
```

---

In the example below, we can assume that `MyScript` is the name of our script.

**1**.You need dictionary that can hold the name of the name and the int array.

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> boxes
```

**2**.You need a way to convert **`"box"+2`** or **`arrayVariableName`** to the current script instance. This can be done with the implicit conversion operator feature in C#. You can pass **`"box"+2`** or **`arrayVariableName`** into this implicit MyScript and then store it into a global variable for the next step.

```
//The global variable that holds the arrayVariableName to access
static string targetBox = null;

//Implicit conversion operators (box array name to this script(MyScript) instance)
public static implicit operator MyScript(string box)
{
    return setTargetAndGetInstance(box);
}

public static MyScript setTargetAndGetInstance(string box)
{
    if (instance.boxes.ContainsKey(box))
    {
        //Set the box requested. This will be needed in the Indexer overloading above
        targetBox = box;
        return instance;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

**3**.Now, you can implement **`[index]`** syntax. This can be accomplished with the indexer overloading feature.

```
//Indexer overloading (index to int (value in array))
public int this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        //Get value based on value set in the implicit operators
        return accessBox(targetBox, index);
    }
}
```

Now, when you do, **`"box"+2`**, it will return the instance of this(`MyScript`) with the help of the `implicit` conversion operator. It will then allow you to do **`[random int]`** with the indexer overloading feature.

---

With the code below here is the example of the syntax in your question and other similar methods to do this. <sup>Included similar ones since they look nicer than what you are requesting</sup>:

With a simple function:

```
int test1 = accessBox("box" + 2, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3));
Debug.Log(test1);
```

With the `arrayVariableName [index]` syntax:

<sup>You are looking for this but the casting to `MyScript` looks awful</sup>

```
int test2 = ((MyScript)("box" + 2))[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)];
Debug.Log(test2);
```

With the `[arrayVariableName][index]` syntax:

```
int test3 = this["box" + 2][UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)];
Debug.Log(test3);
```

With the `[arrayVariableName, index]` syntax

```
int test4 = this["box" + 2, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)];
Debug.Log(test4);
```

Complete functional example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int[] box1 = { 1, 0, 2 };
    public int[] box2 = { 3, 1, 0 };
    public int[] box3 = { 2, 3, 1 };


    public Dictionary<string, int[]> boxes = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
    private static MyScript instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;

        //Add to Dictionary
        addBox();

        int test1 = accessBox("box" + 2, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3));
        Debug.Log(test1);

        int test2 = ((MyScript)("box" + 2))[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)];
        Debug.Log(test2);

        int test3 = this["box" + 2][UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)];
        Debug.Log(test3);

        int test4 = this["box" + 2, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3)];
        Debug.Log(test4);
    }

    void addBox()
    {
        boxes.Add("box1", box1);
        boxes.Add("box2", box2);
        boxes.Add("box3", box3);
    }

    public int accessBox(string box, int index)
    {
        //Return the array from the Dictionary
        int[] tempVar;
        if (boxes.TryGetValue(box, out tempVar))
        {
            //Return the spicified index
            return tempVar[index];
        }
        else
        {
            //ERROR - return -1
            return -1;
        }
    }


    //Indexer overloading (index to int (value in array))
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            //Get value based on value set in the implicit operators
            return accessBox(targetBox, index);
        }
    }

    static string targetBox = null;

    //Implicit conversion operators (box array name to this script(MyScript) instance)
    public static implicit operator MyScript(string box)
    {
        return setTargetAndGetInstance(box);
    }

    public static MyScript setTargetAndGetInstance(string box)
    {
        if (instance.boxes.ContainsKey(box))
        {
            //Set the box requested. This will be needed in the Indexer overloading above
            targetBox = box;
            return instance;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    //Indexer overloading (box array name to this script(MyScript) instance)
    public MyScript this[string box]
    {
        get
        {
            return setTargetAndGetInstance(box);
        }
    }

    //Indexer overloading (box array name to int)
    public int this[string box, int index]
    {
        get
        {
            setTargetAndGetInstance(box);
            return accessBox(box, index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a generic solution to your problem, using `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`:**

Main code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Class1
{
    public void Example()
    {
        // a dictionary with string keys

        var string1 = "abcd";
        var string2 = "efgh";

        var dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
        {
            {string1, new[] {0, 1, 2}},
            {string2, new[] {3, 4, 5}}
        };


        // a dictionary with custom type

        var box1 = new Box(10, 10);
        var box2 = new Box(20, 20);

        var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<Box, int[]>
        {
            {box1, new[] {0, 1, 2}},
            {box2, new[] {3, 4, 5}}
        };

        // get random value from both dictionnaries

        var i1 = GetRandomInteger(dictionary1, string1);
        var i2 = GetRandomInteger(dictionary2, box1);
    }

    private int GetRandomInteger<TKey>(IDictionary<TKey, int[]> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();

        var array = dictionary[key];

        // prefer UnityEngine.Random here since it's static 
        var index = new Random().Next(array.Length);

        var value = array[index];

        return value;
    }
}
```

Extra code:

```
public struct Box
{
    // a dictionary key should be immutable, therefore I use a struct
    // implement equality members so that when querying the dictionary,
    // it will find the value associated to the key
    // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type

    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }

    public Box(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public bool Equals(Box other)
    {
        return Width == other.Width && Height == other.Height;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        return obj is Box && Equals((Box) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Width * 397) ^ Height;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Box left, Box right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Box left, Box right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
}
```